# Limit of these integrals

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

The integral is not that easy to solve, even Mathematica or Matlab didn't produce a solution. However if the limit can be moved inside the integral, then the integral is more easy to be solved.

Can the limit be moved inside the following integrals? or does anyone know how to solve these integrals?

$$\lim_{\sigma \to 0}\int_{0}^{\pi } \frac{\left (\sin \theta -2h  \right )}{\left ( 1+\cos \theta  \right )^{2}+\left ( 2h-\sin \theta  \right )^{2}}e^{i\sigma \cos \theta }\sin \theta d\theta$$

$$\lim_{\sigma \to 0}\int_{0}^{\pi } e^{j\sigma \cos \theta }Re\left [\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{-ia_{n}}{\left (e^{-i\theta }+2ih  \right )^{n}} \right ] \sin \theta d\theta$$

Thank you

Comment: The first limit is $\pi$. Concerning the second limit, what is known about $a_n$?

Comment: How you solved the first limit? did you solved the integral first? how? $a_{n}$ is a coefficient whose value changes with n, but is just a number, it doesn't depend on $\theta $

Comment: also $a_{n}$ does not depend on $\sigma$